# Creating a game board using struct

Tags: c, struct

So I am making a game board for battle ship, but I am trying to use a struct to make it. Currently I am getting an error when trying to create the game board.  I'm trying to make it this way so that when the user inputs coordinates for the ships, or when they are making a move I can easily change symbols and get to the correct coordinate on the array. This is what I am working with right now. I am using 3 file format, so I put all the parts down below.

I could create the board without using a struct, but I'm pretty sure I need to create it this way so that I am able to manipulate the board later.

If this helps this is my current error: Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'person' is being used without being initialized.

This is in the header file

```
typedef struct game_board
{
    int board[10][10];
    int row;
    int col;
    char symbol;
    }Game_Board;

Game_Board initalize_game_board(Game_Board player);
```

The function

```
Game_Board initalize_game_board(Game_Board player)
{
    int row_index = 0, col_index = 0;

    printf("  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
    for (row_index = 0; row_index < player.row; row_index++)
    {
        printf("%d ", row_index);
        for (col_index = 0; col_index < player.col; col_index++)
        {
            player.board[row_index][col_index] = player.symbol;
            printf("%c ", player.board[row_index][col_index]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

In the main function

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *outfile = NULL;
    outfile = fopen("battleship.log", "w");

    Game_Board person, computer;
    int who_goes_first = 0;

    strcpy(person.symbol, '~');
    person.row = 10;
    person.col = 10;
    strcpy(computer.symbol, '~');
    computer.row = 10;
    computer.col = 10;

    welcome_screen(outfile);
    printf("Player 1\n");


   initalize_game_board(person);
```

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: Does this code even compile? `initalize_game_board` does not return any value.

Comment: Sorrry! Creating the board returns an error now, So I am trying to get it to work using the struct

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski no it does not, I assumed it was because of the code currently, when I try to return a value at the end of the function I get "return value type does not match function type"

Comment: You forgot to tell us *what* you tried to return.

Comment: Look out for compiler warnings from such as `strcpy(person.symbol, '~');`

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm trying to get the 10 by 10 grid to print so that I can see that the game board works. I did this without using my struct variables, but I think I need to do it with a struct so that I can change symbols / put ships and stuff later. But now I am getting a run time error, and I am assuming it is a problem with my struct, but I do not know what it is. And that is why I am asking for help

Comment: @WeatherVane Is there another way to do chars with a struct beside using strcpy?

Comment: `person.symbol = '~';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need return statements for both functions. Ending paren for main().

Highly recommend

```
computer.symbol = '~';
```

Instead of

```
strcpy(computer.symbol, '~');
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i guess i was just trying the wrong this :)\

Comment: It will compile after assigning a char instead of calling strcpy.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Ryan's answer, strcpy() assumes the source string has a null terminator, to know how many characters are to be copied. In your case, there is no null terminator in the source string. strcpy() will not stop copying till a null character is read from memory. Since you are using a single character, a simple assignment statement will do!

Also, in function initalize_game_board(), consider passing the pointer to the Game_Board structure, instead of the structure itself. When you do this, you can change the contents of the actual structure (struct 'person' in this case), by using the arrow (->) operator, within the function itself. Then you will not have to return the structure  from this function. With your current design, you are creating a temporary copy of the structure, then populating it, and then (probably after modifications!) returning that structure, which will again be copied to the structure 'person'.